# Share internet over USB

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, usb, internet

I have my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B connected to the internet via an ethernet cable. 
I now have a second device (It's an android phone, but that's not important) that I connect to the Raspberry Pi via USB.

I now want to share the internet FROM my Raspberry Pi TO my second device.

Is this possible? Is there any software for that.

PS. Yes, I know the easier way is to create a WiFi hotspot via a dongle, but I'm interested in an alternative without wireless connections.

Comment: The model and OS of the phone matter a great deal since you will need to have the phone's USB port configured as an OTG port.

Comment: With a Pi model that can be used as a USB gadget it could work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gnirehtet. It's "Tethering" backwards, as it just installs a really small app, that then creates a VPN and tunnels all traffic to the Pi. Works great, has a notification if it's connected and so on. But it doesn't have a UI.
[Gnirehtet Github](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet). Just download the Java version, run it with the argument "autostart", so you can plug in unlimited devices and it automatically starts the tethering.

```
./gnirehtet autostart
```

In the downloaded and unpacked directory (there is a gnirehtet file, which just runs the Java file, if you want you can *java -jar* directly)